# Significance of the normalization of the left Perron eigenvector

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-theory

Let $A$ be a positive square matrix. Perron-Frobenius theory says that there exist $\lambda, v$ with $Av = \lambda v$ and $\lambda$ equals the spectral radius of $A$, $\lambda$ is simple, and $v$ is positive.

Now consider also the left Perron eigenvector $u^T A = \lambda u^T$. Another result of Perron-Frobenius theory is that
$$\lim_{m \to \infty} \left( \frac{A}{\lambda} \right)^m = \frac{v u^T}{u^T v}.$$

Suppose $\| v \| = 1$. The above result says that **the "correct" normalization for $u$ is $u^T v = 1$ rather than the more usual $u^T u = \| u \|^2 = 1$**. This motivates the question: what is the significance of the ratio
$$\frac{u^T v}{u^T u}?$$

Are there matrices $A$ for which this ratio is arbitrarily large? Arbitrarily small? Does this ratio determine any properties of $A$? Note that if $A$ is symmetric, then $u = v$ and this ratio is always equal to $1$, but that's not the case in general for arbitrary $A$. Could it be the case that this ratio is measuring how far $A$ is from being symmetric?

Note too that this normalization is necessary so that the limit $\frac{vu^T}{u^T v}$ is a projection matrix (i.e. that its only non-zero eigenvalue is one). In this context, I understand why the normalization is necessary, but **I'm interested in the amount of normalization necessary with respect to the length of $u$**.

Any pointers appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The normalisation here is to keep the matrix's only nonzero eigenvalue or trace equal to $1$.

Comment: @user1551 yes I understand that the normalization results in the limit matrix being a projection matrix onto the corresponding eigenspace. But I'm interested in distinct cases where that normalization is larger or smaller.

Comment: For your main question, consider that $uv^T$ has rank one and is a projector(/is idempotent) iff it has trace 1.  The result again is very natural in the case of markov chains since $\frac{A}{\lambda} = A$ and it just says that $A^m \to $ a distribution that doesn't depend on starting state.  Also consider generic case where $A$ is diagonalizable, if $A = PDP^{-1}$ this *implies* that $u^T v = 1$  (why?) and hence $vu^T$ is idempotent

Comment: @user8675309 Yes, please see latest edit.